# Bootstrap form control in navigation menu does not seems to resize correclty

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design, search-form

I have made a navigation menu with Bootstrap and in this navigation I have placed the search form in the middle of the menu. Then I adjusted the width of it to 500px for desktop devices and for tablet devices I made 300px wide.

Here's the CSS code:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translatex(-50%);
    }
    .form-group input{
        width:500px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 499px) {
    .form-group input{
        width:300px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 399px) {
    .form-group input{
        width:200px !important;
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML code of the navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="log"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default sign">Default</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The problem is that the size of search form input in desktop devices still stocks at 200px somehow!!

So if you know how to handle this problem please let me know. Basically all I want is to escape these kinds of problems (as you can see in this image) that may happens in smaller devices...

[image: print screen]

Answer (score 0):

Each CSS media query is overriding the previous one, so for any width greater than 398px the width of the `input` will be `200px`. To fix this you just need to reverse the order of the queries:

```
@media (min-width: 399px) {
    .form-group input{
        width:200px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 499px) {
    .form-group input{
        width:300px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translatex(-50%);
    }
    .form-group input{
        width:500px !important;
    }
}
```

However, if you just want to avoid the input being too wide you might be better off with something like [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc).